# How to form URLs with loopback rest connector?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I created an API endpoint like:

```
GET /etablissementDetails/{id}
```

Here is my `datasources.json` file:

```
  "etablissementDetailsREST": {
"name": "etablissementDetailsREST",
"crud": false,
"connector": "rest",
"debug": false,
"options": {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "strictSSL": false
},
"operations": [
  {
    "template": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://data.education.gouv.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=fr-en-adresse-et-geolocalisation-etablissements-premier-et-second-degre",
      "headers": {
        "accepts": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "query": {
        "q": "{id}"
      },
      "options": {
        "strictSSL": true,
        "useQuerystring": true
      },
      "responsePath": "$.records.*"
    },
    "functions": {
      "{id}": ["id"]
    }
  }
]}
```

In loopback explorer, if I enter as an idea and click on Try me out (Run the GET), I am getting the following:

[http://localhost:3000/api/v1/etablissementDetails/{id}?id=0593904Y](http://localhost:3000/api/v1/etablissementDetails/%7Bid%7D?id=0593904Y)

I would like the **{id}** to be replaced by **0593904Y** directly in the URL to become http://localhost:3000/api/v1/etablissementDetails/0593904Y

Comment: Your model definition looks very different from the ones I have normally seen. How did you create this?

Comment: I created it manually as the loopback rest connector needs a manual model setup.

Comment: Ah okay. So this is your datasources.json file, not your model definition. I somehow took it as model definition.

Comment: There is almost nothing in the model definition as it is defined by the external API.